# How to use an if function to call elements of an array

Tags: java, arrays, if-statement

Basically, I have a variable 'prime'. It can only take values between 0 and 6. Based on its value, I want a string 'result' to be Sunday if prime is 0, Monday if 1, etc. Currently, it's coded this way:

```
String result = new String();

    if (prime == 0)
    {
        result = "Sunday";
    }

    if (prime == 1)
    {
        result = "Monday";
    }

    if (prime == 2)
    {
        result = "Tuesday";
    }

    if (prime == 3)
    {
        result = "Wednesday";
    }

    if (prime == 4)
    {
        result = "Thursday";
    }

    if (prime == 5)
    {
        result = "Friday";
    }

    if (prime == 6)
    {
        result = "Saturday";
    }

    else
    {
        result = "Check your code.";
    }
```

I'm wondering if there's a faster way to do this? I've created an array with the days of the week:

```
String[] days = new String[7];

    days [0] = "Sunday";
    days [1] = "Monday";
    days [2] = "Tuesday";
    days [3] = "Wednesday";
    days [4] = "Thursday";
    days [5] = "Friday";
    days [6] = "Saturday";
```

How do I quickly and elegantly code it so that if the value of prime is 0, the string 'result' is the first element of the array, and so on until if prime is 6, the string 'result' is the seventh element?

Comment: `if (prime >= 0 && prime < days.length) { result = days[prime]; } `...?

Comment: don't use `if` use `if else` or `switch case` for this

Comment: @MadProgrammer you should really make that an an answer, possibly with an explanation on how youre just using the array to lookup the value. You did get it first after all

Comment: @TheveshTheva you don't need curly brackets if the contents of the `if` block is only one line

Comment: Are you dead set on your number sequence for days?  There's DayOfWeek.values() that already has a look up but it's from Monday - Sunday (0 - 6) respectively.

Comment: @UnknownOctopus but even  don't need curly brackets it's good practice to use curly brackets

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You already have all the valid values stored in a simple lookup table, you just need to ensure that the requested value is within the range of available values.

The basic answer would be to do something like...

```
if (prime >= 0 && prime < days.length) { 
    result = days[prime]; 
} else {
    result = prime + " is not within a valid range";
    // Or throw an exception
}
```

What this does is makes sure that the `prime` value is within the valid range of acceptable values (`0..days.length - 1`), other wise it returns an error message (or you could throw an exception).

Remember, arrays are `0` indexed, hence the need to use `< days.length` (less then) and not `<= days.length` (less then or equals to)

Comment: This can be also faced using the DayOfWeek class, there is no need to maintain an array with all the days of the week

Comment: @gastonmancini Didn't you already have this discussion.  This also assumes the OP is using Java 8.  But I've gone beyond the idea of the OP "is storing days" and gone to providing a solution for getting values from a array

Comment: You are right that solution assumes that is using Java 8.

Comment: In the case you are using Java 8 and above ... with that class you avoid to use a conditional statement and to have an object with the days of the week.

Comment: Glad it could help.  There's some other good ideas floating around that you might consider having a look at ;)

Answer (score 5):

You were close. For those saying Switch or if chains, it's overkill for this problem.

```
result = days[Math.abs(prime % days.length)];
```

The array acts like a switch statement, and the modulus operator wrapped in the `Math.abs` (absolute value) acts like a safety net to stay with in the valid range of the array 0-6.

> Credits to @MadProgrammer for the `Math.abs`

From [Tutorials Point](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/java_basic_operators.htm)

> **Modulus** - Divides left hand operand by right hand operand and returns remainder

Comment: While I appreciate `%` to maintain a rolling index within a valid range, as a bigger, I'd be tempted to just use a simple range checking `if` statement for simplicity - but that's just - nothing wrong with the approach, but it could raise more questions then it solves

Comment: @jay harris that's true.but whenever not use a array like in op's first attempt it's not good to use if because only one if command should be executed.pointing it isn't bad right

Comment: @MadProgrammer I say this is the simpler approach and yours is the more extensible. lol rolling index, rolling days right?

Comment: @FastSnail your english is a little broken mate.?

Comment: Negative values will cause it to fail ;)

Comment: @MadProgrammer mind blown lol i didn't go with the if because you already commented it, I don't see the need for duplicate answers, thus the alternate ;)

Comment: @JayHarris As I said, I don't mind the modular approach (and you could use `Math.abs` to get over the negative number issue ;)), I'd just be concerned with the OP's ability to understand it right now ;)

Answer (score 2):

Why don't you use the [`DayOfWeek`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/DayOfWeek.html) class?

```
import java.time.DayOfWeek;
```

and try this...

```
try {
     DayOfWeek dayOfWeek = DayOfWeek.of(++prime);
     System.out.println(dayOfWeek.getDisplayName(TextStyle.FULL, Locale.getDefault()));
} catch (java.time.DateTimeException ex) {
     System.out.println("Invalid value for DayOfWeek");
}
```

Note that we have to do `++prime` since your code starts in zero and the enum in one.

If you have to set *Sunday* as the first day (instead of *Monday* that is the first in the enum)... the `minus` method will do the trick:

```
DayOfWeek dayOfWeek = DayOfWeek.of(++prime).minus(1);
```

EDIT: advantages and disadvantages of the solution

*Pros*:

- Don't require an object to maintain your days.
- Don't use a conditional statement.
- The text style and language can easily be changed.

*Cons*:

- java 1.8 is required

Comment: I already asked this as a comment.  DayOfWeek.values() is Mon - Sun (0 - 6) respectively and DayOfWeek.of() is Mon - Sun (1 - 7) respectively.  As it stands, the OP says they want Sun - Sat (0 - 6) respectively.

Comment: That is solved with the `minus` or the `plus` method of the same class

Comment: What about locales where the day of week starts on `Sunday`?

Comment: The locals are only used for formatting in this `getDisplayName` method, so won't affect it.

Answer (score 1):

You could simply do:

```
if (prime >= 0 && prime < days.length) result = days[prime];
else result = "Check your code."
```

Because `prime` is essentially the index of the day that you want.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Enum and define yourself

```
public enum Week {
    SUNDAY(1, "Sunday"), Monday(2, "Monday"), TUESDAY(3, "Tuesday"), WEDNESDAY(
            4, "Wednesday"), THURSDAY(6, "Thursday"), FRIDAY(6, "Friday"), SATURDAY(
            7, "Saturday");
    private int id;
    private String name;

    static Map<Integer, String> map = new HashMap<Integer, String>();
    static {
        for (Week w : Week.values()) {
            map.put(w.getId(), w.name);
        }
    }

    private Week(int id, String name) {
        this.setId(id);
        this.setName(name);
    }

    public static String getNameById(int id) {
        return map.get(id);
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }
}
```

Comment: Or just set it up so that `Week.values()[0]` return `Sunday`?

Comment: Thank you very much, @creazymole ! In this case, MadProgrammer's suggestion works best for me, but your answer taught me something new!